# how to I can know the driver connection in a grails controller

Tags: grails, datasource, connector

I need know if my grails app is using the MySQL, PostgreSQL or Oracle connector, then in a Controller I need switching the cases depending of the connection that it has configured

```
def conn = <any class and method for know the connection>
switch(conn){
   case 'my': .....
       breal
   case 'pg': .....
       breal
   case 'ora': .....
       breal
   default: .....
       breal
}
```

Please if you can help me... thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

```
def dbDriver = grailsApplication.config.dataSource.driverClassName
```